# OpenGL bad performance in Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm working in a videogame for Android using OpenGL 1.0.

I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html

I have created a little demo that works very well and fluid (limited to 30 FPS) in my current mobile: HTC Sensation (Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich).

Also, I tested my game in my friend's mobiles with the next results:

- Galaxy S2 = perfect! (30FPS)
- Galaxy Note = perfect! (30FPS)
- HTC One S = perfect! (30FPS)
- Sony Xperia Tipo = perfect! (30FPS)
- Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 = very bad performance >_<' (<10FPS and tested in two mobiles)

If you compare the specs between Xperia Tipo and Samsung Ace you can see that they are almost the same mobile.

XPERIA TIPO:

- 320 x 480 resolution
- 512MB RAM
- Qualcomm MSM7227A 800MHz, GPU Adreno 200

SAMSUNG GALAXY ACE:

- 320 x 480 resolution
- 278MB RAM
- Qualcomm MSM7227 800 MHz, GPU Adreno 200

OK, the RAM is different, but my game is very simple, does not consume more than 200MB! But the performance is totally different. No sense!

However... only one thing is different! Samsung Galaxy Ace uses Android 2.3.X (Gingerbread) and Xperia Tipo uses Android 4.0.3 (ICS).

So, my spearhead is targetting that the problem is with Android 2.3.X - Gingerbread or Galaxy Ace is a trash mobile.

But... I forced my friends to install the AndEngine Examples and test it, with the result that the Nexus ParticleSystem test works very well and fluid.

I'm totally lost! Why this different in performance? What I'm doing wrong?

Some extra info:

1. I follow all the steps from that tutorial.
2. I use GL10 (OpenGL 1.0).
3. No shaders.
4. No delta time for lost FPS (I do not think this thing is going to solve my problem).
5. No native code, just Java.
6. SystemClock.uptimemillis() and sleep() to control FPS.
7. MediaPlayer to play one MIDI song (no more sounds).
8. Textures with a lot of alpha (2D game, is neccesary for sprites).
9. minSDKversion=8

If you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: Some suggestions: Perhaps GC is going wild? Try to strip your app until the problem disappears. Try to profile your app.

Comment: Well I think 200 MB isn't that small. You may try to detect ram capacity at the begining then reduce bitmap sizes to half if necessery. Anyway even this didn't solved my problem on Ace. It looks like Aces have a special problem about this.

Answer (score 0):

The RAM may be the bottleneck. You know that Android does not handle images very well. Are you recycling your bitmaps? 
Why don't you use OpenGL ES 2.0? I am developing games and testing in a Samsung Galaxy Ace, and LG p500 (both with Gingerbread) without problems. I can get almost 50 FPS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread, it is very very bad.
2. Use `statics`; this is a bad OOP practice, but useful here.
3. Use `vertex-buffer objects`
4. Initialize in `onSurfaceChanged` and fetch locations (`glget***location`) here too.
5. It is not your fault always because on Froyo, garbage collector is bad and then on Gingerbread, `the touch drivers fire way too many events` (Google I_O 2011_ Memory management for Android Apps). So, gradually switch to other input methods for your app/game that do not use touch like android motion and position sensors

Comment: because i experienced this and went on to solve it using statics, avoiding use of sleep, and switching to vbos